# Antiferromagnetic-like interaction, but preferring 120/240 angles instead of 180?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, computational-physics, spin-models

Antiferromagnetic interaction energetically prefers opposite spins for neighbors: rotated by 180 degrees.

But imagine there is $S_3$ symmetry: 3 possibilities rotated by 120 degrees and antiferromagnetic-like interaction: preferring 120 or 240 degree difference for neighboring spins (fixed projection: $\cos(\varphi)=-1/2$).

Deciding if originally continuous angles can optimize to only such 120/240 degree angles for a general graph is [3-coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) NP-complete problem.

Can such $S_3$-type antiferromagnetic interaction be realized in physical systems?

Is it considered in literature? E.g. some spin glasses to solve NP-complete problems?

Comment: Hint: if it's a classical system that can be efficiently simulated in a classical computer (which is the case here) and whose equilibria (or other properties) solve NP-complete problems without any fundamental pitfalls, then that simulation could be used to solve the problem entirely *in silico* without bothering with the physical construction. For something that trivial, if the computer scientists are not doing it, there's a reason. So why not cut the off-topic question in the lay paragraph?

Comment: The general issue with conversion of NP problem into global optimization problem, also e.g. for adiabatic QC, is exponential number of local minima ([slides with lots of examples](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwyxf44u38i42d8/pnpslides.pdf)) - e.g. gradient descent will most likely stuck. Spin glasses were considered for adiabatic QC (e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.5843.pdf ), but usually with discrete spins in complex systems - here is direct translation into optimization of continuous angles ... and the question is interesting from physics perspective as S3 symmetry is quite common (e.g. NH3).